# Image Upload failed in some case Using Web API

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2, fine-uploader

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> NewTeamLogo(int teamId, string qqfile, HttpRequestMessage request, string root, string urlString)
{
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    Team team = this._teamRepository.Find(a => a.TeamId == teamId).FirstOrDefault();
    var resultTask = task.ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(readTask =>
    {
        try
        {
            string newfilename = string.Empty;

            var inputFileName =  provider.FileData.First().Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;

            if (inputFileName.Contains("\""))
                inputFileName = inputFileName.Substring(1, inputFileName.Length - 2);
            var tempfile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFileName);

            var fileName = string.Format("t{0}.Gif", teamId, tempfile);

            var localFileName = provider.FileData.First().LocalFileName;

            var file = new FileInfo(localFileName);

            newfilename = string.Format("t{0}.Gif", teamId);

            var newpath = Path.Combine(file.DirectoryName, fileName);

            var existingFileName = team.Logo != null ? team.Logo : "";

            var existingPath = Path.Combine(file.DirectoryName, existingFileName);

            if (File.Exists(existingPath))
            {
                File.Delete(existingPath);
            }

            File.Move(file.FullName, newpath);

            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(root, fileName)))
            {
                Size thumbnailSize = GetThumbnailSize(image);
                Image thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(thumbnailSize.Width, thumbnailSize.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                var tFileName = string.Format("{0}.Gif", teamId);

                var tPath = Path.Combine(root, tFileName);

                using (var tScope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    thumbnail.Save(tPath);
                    team.Logo = tFileName;
                    this._teamRepository.Update(team);
                    this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
                    tScope.Complete();
                }
            }
            File.Delete(newpath);

            return this.Response("true", "success");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Response("false", ex.ToString());
        }
    });

    return resultTask;

}
```

On My local system its working fine but on Live server getting failed some time due to not found bodypart file.

Printed error on console as follows:

> {"success": false, "error": "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '\Upload\App_Team\BodyPart_3bab8f56-f69d-49f4-bb75-1524bd83639f'.
>   File name: 'Upload\App_Team\BodyPart_3bab8f56-f69d-49f4-bb75-1524bd83639f'
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.File.InternalMove(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean checkHost)
>      at Brightspot.Opband.Uow.TeamUow.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(Task`1 readTask)"}

Comment: Have you checked the write permission in that server? Perhaps it also caused this error?

Answer (score 0):

If the uploads only occasionally fail, it's clearly not a permissions issue.  Something is reading the file out of the multipart encoded request sent by Fine Uploader, and saving it to a temporary file. In fact that may be a side effect of some of the code in your question. My guess is that this temporary file, read from the request, is being cleaned up prematurely, or perhaps it is not being saved at all due to some other error, such as a request size restriction in your production environment. All other things being equal, you'll need to examine how your production server is configured, compared to your development environment where this is not failing.